# Excel User-defined functions can't use ArgumentDescriptions in Excel 2007. I'm trying to bypass it in my Add

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I have created a couple of user-defined functions in Excel and created a simple add-in so that I can share them with colleagues.

I use Application.MacroOptions in order to give some useful indications for how to use the functions. Especially, I use ArgumentDescriptions to give descriptions for the arguments.

```
Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc _
      HelpFile:= Helpfile
```

I have just found out that the ArgumentDescriptions parameter is not supported in Excel 2007 and this is causing an error for this version. Excluding this parameter solves the problem.

I don't want to have to distribute two versions of the add-in. I tried to use this code to include the parameter if the version more recent than Excel 2007, but it still gets tripped up on the unrecognized parameter name if used in Excel 2007:

```
If Left(Application.Version, 2) > 12 Then
     Application.MacroOptions Macro:=FuncName, ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End If
```

Is there a way to solve this problem so I can do this all with just one add-in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get around the `Named argument not found` error in the your function is to move the setting of the macro options into 2 separate functions:

```
 If Left(Application.Version, 2) > 12 Then
    setUpNewMacroOptions
 Else
    setUpOldMacroOptions
 End If
```

And then the 2 functions:

```
 Public Sub setUpOldMacroOptions()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myMacro", Description:="desc", Category:="cat", HelpFile:="file"
 End Sub

 Public Sub setUpNewMacroOptions()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myMacro", Description:="desc", Category:="cat", ArgumentDescriptions:="blah", HelpFile:="file"
 End Sub
```

As the `setUpNewMacroOptions` function is never called in Excel 2007, the VBA compiler doesn't try to validate the function so no error.

Comment: There will be a compile error in Excel 2007, you mean no runtime error will occur. The correct solution is to use conditional compilation: see below.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure works in Excel 2010 with argument descriptiors and in 2007 without them:

```
    Private Sub AddDesc(Macro As String, Description As String, _
Category As String, ArgumentDescriptions As Variant)
        #If VBA7 Then 'in Excel 2010 and over
            Application.MacroOptions Macro:=Macro, Description:=Description, _
                Category:=Category, ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgumentDescriptions
        #Else 'in Excel 2007 and under
            Application.MacroOptions Macro:=Macro, Description:=Description, _
                Category:=Category
        #End If
    End Sub
```

Best regards,
Peter Krassoi